# «Кто знает(,) может(,) посоветует что-нибудь» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, члены-предложения

Как расставить запятые в предложении:
**Кто знает(,) может(,) посоветует что-нибудь.**

«Кто знает может» — это подлежащее. «Может» могло бы быть вводным словом, но если его отбросить, то теряется смысл предложения. А если выделить с двух сторон запятыми, то будет неясно: *может знает* или *может посоветует*.

Как разобрать это предложение и как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

«Кто знает, может, посоветует что-нибудь» - сложноподчинённое предложение. Смысл: Кто знает, тот, может, посоветует что-нибудь. Главное предложение неполное с пропуском подлежащего, которое восстанавливается из контекста. Сказуемое "посоветует".

Придаточное местоимённо-определительное. Кто - подлежащее, знает - сказуемое.

Может - вводное слово со значением неуверенности. Не думаю, что, если выделить с двух сторон запятыми, будет неясно: "может, знает" или "может, посоветует". По-моему, здесь сразу понятно, что ко второй части предложения. Я бы выделила вводное с двух сторон. Но правило говорит, что при неясной отнесённости вводного слова запятая ставится с одной стороны, не отделяя его от предложения, к которому оно относится: «Кто знает, может посоветует что-нибудь».

Answer (score 1):

**Кто знает, может,  посоветует что-нибудь.**

Мне кажется, что это местоименно-определительное предложение имеет дополнительную **условную модификацию значения**, так как описывает предполагаемую ситуацию (**если** кто знает, тот, может, посоветует).

При этом позицию пропущенного указательного слова ТОТ занимает вводное слово "может", которое должно   выделяться **как обязательный структурный элемент этого предложения**.

**Примечание.** Следует учесть, что вводные слова могут составлять двухместные союзные образования, например,  вида ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ (если уезжает, значит, ему там нравится), и вводное слово при этом **обососбляется**.

Предложение без обособления вводного слова "Кто знает, может посоветует что-нибудь" **имеет неясную грамматику и неудобно для прочтения.**